# What are some common strategies different compilers use to deal with overflow in numeric conversions?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, type-conversion, integer-overflow, floating-point-conversion

I understand that, in C++, when I convert a `float`/`double` into an `int`, whereby the floating-point number is beyond the range that the `int` can hold, the result is not defined as part of the C++ language. The result depends on the implementation/compiler. **What are some strategies common compilers use to deal with this?**

Converting `7.2E12` to an `int` can yield the values `1634811904` or `2147483647`. For example, does anyone know what the compiler is doing in each of these cases?

Comment: [gcc's implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation).

Comment: Note I am not asking what strategies the programmer should use to avoid/deal with this overflow, I'm asking what different strategies a compiler may employ to deal with it

Comment: @user657267 Your link does not describe the behavior of GCC-generated programs for the overflow in the conversion from floating-point to integer. In fact, that links describes implementation-defined behaviors in GCC, whereas this overflow is undefined behavior (you cannot expect a compiler to document what it does for it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler generates sequences of instructions that produce the correct result for all inputs that do not cause overflow. This is all it has to worry about (because [overflow in the conversion from floating-point to integer is undefined behavior](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/10/09/Overflow-float-integer)). **The compiler does not “deal with” overflows so much as completely ignore them**. If the underlying assembly instruction(s) on the platform raise an exception, fine. If they wrap around, fine. If they produce nonsensical results, again, fine.

---

As an example, constant expressions may be converted to integers at compile-time with rules that differ from the behavior of the assembly instructions generated on the platform. My blog post gives the example:

```
int printf(const char *, ...);

volatile double v = 0;

int main()
{
  int i1 = 2147483648.0;
  int i2 = 2147483648.0 + v;
  printf("%d %d\n", i1, i2);
}
```

which produces a program that prints two different values for `i1` and `i2`. This is because the conversion in the computation of `i1` was applied at compile-time, whereas the conversion in the computation of `i2` was applied at run-time.

---

As another example, in the particular case of the conversion from `double` to 32-bit `unsigned int` on the x86-64 platform, the results can be funny:

There are no instructions in the x86 instruction sets to convert from floating-point to unsigned integer.

On Mac OS X for Intel, compiling a 64-bit program, the conversion from double to 32-bit unsigned int is compiled in a single instruction: the instruction for 64-bit conversions, `cvttsd2siq`, with destination a 64-bit register of which only the bottom 32-bit will subsequently be used as the 32-bit unsigned integer it represents:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int c, char **v)
{
  unsigned int i = 4294967296.0 + strtod(v[1], 0);
  printf("%u\n", i);
}
$ gcc -m64 -S -std=c99 -O t.c && cat t.s
…
addsd LCPI1_0(%rip), %xmm0 ; this is the + from the C program
cvttsd2siq %xmm0, %rsi ; one-instruction conversion
…
```

This explains how, on that platform, a result modulo 2<sup>32</sup> can be obtained for doubles that are small enough (specifically, small enough to fit in a signed 64-bit integer).

In the old IA-32 instruction set, there is no instruction to convert a `double` to a 64-bit signed integer (and there is no instruction to convert a `double` to a 32-bit `unsigned int` either). The conversion to 32-bit `unsigned int` has to be done by combining a few of the instructions that do exist, including two instructions `cvttsd2si` to convert from double to 32-bit signed integer:

```
$ gcc -m32 -S -std=c99 -O t.c && cat t.s
…
addsd LCPI1_0-L1$pb(%esi), %xmm0 ; this is the + from the C program
movsd LCPI1_1-L1$pb(%esi), %xmm1 ; conversion to unsigned int starts here
movapd %xmm0, %xmm2
subsd %xmm1, %xmm2
cvttsd2si %xmm2, %eax
xorl $-2147483648, %eax
ucomisd %xmm1, %xmm0
cvttsd2si %xmm0, %edx
cmovael %eax, %edx
…
```

Two alternative solutions are computed, respectively in `%eax` and in `%edx`. The alternatives are each correct on different definition domains. If the number to convert, in `%xmm0`, is larger than the constant 2<sup>31</sup> in `%xmm1`, then one alternative is chosen, otherwise, the other one is. The high-level algorithm, using only conversions from double to int, would be:

```
if (d < 231)
then (unsigned int)(int)d
else (231 + (unsigned int)(int)(d - 231))
```

This translation of the C conversion from double to unsigned int gives the same saturating behavior as the 32-bit conversion instruction that it relies on:

```
$ gcc -m32 -std=c99 -O t.c && ./a.out 123456
0
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer Pascal! I'm still having trouble bending to the fact that there are undefined behaviour in C/C++. There's still a bit of confusion and I want to clarify one concept: If the compiler doesn't define the instruction for a specific type of conversion that leads to overflow, it may a) find an alternative set of instructions where the result doesn't overflow and then truncates it (like only the 'bottom-32 bit' of a 64-bit integer will be used), or b) ignore it completely, where it is up to the assembly instruction(s) what results it comes back with. Am I close?

Comment: @dayuloli I think you have it. One single assembly instruction usually has a defined behavior (assembly is more thoroughly defined than C or C++). If the compiler always generated this single assembly instruction, you could expect the behavior of the underlying instruction to apply to the source-level overflow. Unfortunately, the translation of source code to assembly is more complex than this. “Constant folding” optimization may mean that the conversion is done at compile-time, and in this case the compiler does not need to match the run-time behavior. And sometimes a single instruction does…

Comment: @dayuloli …not exist for the conversion, in which case the compiler produces a sequence of instruction that does not have to have a clean, easily described behavior for overflows.

Comment: I had to read through your comments a few times, but it clicks! I actually understand everything you said in the comments now, and thanks for making the point about 'Constant folding', that is new to me! Thanks again!

Comment: +1 nice answer ... @dayuloli there is indeed undefined behavior, there is a [whole tag dedicated to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior).

Comment: Hi Shafik, thanks again for your answer to my previous question. But as a person who deals with PHP and Javascript/CSS, getting my head around undefined behaviour isn't as easy as I'd first hoped. But this clears things up even more now.

Comment: _The compiler does not “deal with” overflows so much as completely ignore them._  That's true for most implementations (all that I know, in fact), but because it is undefined behavior, a compiler could generated code to detect and handle them in some specific way.

Comment: Pascal compilers generally have options to generate code for such runtime checks, because such runtime checks are common on Pascal.